# Unable to move items to Trash

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsfilemanager

I am attempting to move items from Downloads to my Trash folder w/out deleting them at first. What am I missing in the implementation below, the files are not moved.

---

Specifics:

```
 NSString *trashpath=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@".Trash"];
 NSString *downloadpath=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Downloads"];
```

---

```
- (void) moveToTrash{
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSArray * list =  [_filemanager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:_downloadpath error:&error];


    //Move items to the trash
    for(id obj in list){
        NSString *sourcepath = [_downloadpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:obj];
        NSString *destpath= [_trashpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:obj];

        if([_filemanager moveItemAtPath:sourcepath toPath:destpath error:&error] == YES)
            NSLog(@"Moved to trash :%@ ",destpath);
        else
            NSLog(@"Unable to move %@ ",sourcepath);

    }
}
```

---

I attempted with the code below as suggested by BergQuester

```
   if([[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] performFileOperation:NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation source:_downloadpath
        destination:@"" files:list tag:nil] == YES)
        NSLog(@"Moved to Trash");
    else
        NSLog(@"Unable to move :%@",[error localizedFailureReason]);
```

I get Unable to move :(null) in my output.

The files are indeed there, so I'm not sure what the issue is still.

Comment: Why do not [trashItemAtURL:resultingItemURL:error](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/trashItemAtURL:resultingItemURL:error:)?

Comment: @JohnSauer, I'd like to avoid iterating through each file and moving individually as suggested by bergquester below.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out what the problem is by logging the error in your else:

```
NSLog(@"Unable to move %@ %@", sourcepath, [error localizedDescription]);
```

Also, unless you abort the loop when you encounter an error, you should reset `error` to `nil`.

Also, you should probably be using `NSWorkspace` and `performFileOperation:NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation` instead of moving each file individually:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] performFileOperation:NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation
                                             source:_downloadpath
                                        destination:@""
                                              files:list
                                                tag:nil];
```

Comment: Well that's not a helpful error. Try the NSWorkspace method I added instead.

Comment: Tried your method, no luck, should destination have a empty sting value ? ===>  destination:@""

Comment: Yes, `NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation` defines where to place the file. (Each volume actually has it's own trash folder). I'm not sure why it isn't working for you off-hand.

Comment: As a side note, users might not be too happy that you are deleting everything in their Downloads folder. That is unless you are creating a utility that does just that.

Comment: I'm creating it for just that, more for personal use and code practice .